# How to insert an <iframe> in an Admin Panel <field>?

Tags: admin, magento-1, system-config, iframe, frontend-model

I'm creating a custom module which displays **Google Maps** in the frontend of Magento. To get those maps the Admin would have to enter and save the URL of the map location in the Admin Panel. This all works fine. The URL is being saved in the database and the maps are displayed in the frontend of the store.

But now I would like to display a preview of this map in the Admin Panel too. This will allow the Admin to easily check whether the correct URL is entered and saved.

I want to display this `Preview Map` in a new `<field>` (just below the field where the URL should be entered) and use a Map Preview `<label>`. The mockup below displays what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

To my modules `system.xml` file I have added the following code:

```
<fields>
    ....
    <preview translate="label comment">
        <label>Map Preview</label>
        <frontend_type>link</frontend_type>
        <frontend_model>mymodule/system_config_map</frontend_model>
        <comment>Preview of your map</comment>
        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </preview>
</fields>
```

And my `MyNamespace/MyModule/Block/System/Config/Map.php` contains the following code:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_System_Config_Map extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) {

    $url = Mage::helper('mymodule')->getMapUrl($store = null);

    return '<iframe style="border: 0;" src="'.$url.'" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="270"></iframe>';
    }
}
```

This does render the Google Map in the Admin Panel and it also renders in the proper `<group>` but it is not loaded in the `<field>` that I want. This is an actual screen shot of the current situation.

[image]

I have tried every `<frontend_type>` I can think of....

So my question is: How can I insert an `<iframe>` in an Admin Panel `<field>`? Should I add something to my `<frontend_model>`?

Comment: I believe using your `<frontend_model>` is indeed the way to go. Within that file you should be able to `$rendered .= '<iframe...`

Comment: What is the `sort_order` of your `'Map Details'` field? Is it less than the `20` used for your `'Map Preview'`?

Answer (score 2):

With `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface` you have the freedom do design the whole row as you want. Since you extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract` and return *only* the iframe in its `render()` method, this is what you get. To use the default table layout, extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element` instead, and use its default `toHtml()` method after modifying the *element* property to display the iframe.

Currently the `render` method will receive a `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Link` as parameter because that's the `frontend_type`, that you specified. But since you don't want to actually show an input field, you should change that to a frontend type where you can more easily replace the rendered output to arbitrary HTML.

I suggest using `label`, then the render method looks like this:

```
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) {

    $url = Mage::helper('mymodule')->getMapUrl($store = null);

    $element->setData('value', '');
    $element->setData('after_element_html', '<iframe style="border: 0;" src="'.$url.'" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="270"></iframe>');

    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

Note that you have to use `after_element_html` and leave `value` empty, because the value of a label is always escaped, while you can always use arbitrary HTML in `after_element_html`

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS class here and remove the width="100%".

```
return '<iframe style="border: 0;" src="'.$url.'" frameborder="0"'
    . ' width="100%" height="270"></iframe>'
;
```

example:

```
return '<iframe class="adminmap" style="border: 0;" src="' . $url
    . '" frameborder="0" width="270" height="270"></iframe>'
;
```

CSS (just guessing on width, and margins)

```
.adminmap { 
    width: 270px !important; 
    margin-left: 50px; 
}
```

You may also want to use `text` for frontend type instead of `link`.

You can find the ***[different types here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element)***.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried them, but unfortunately they didn't help me. All they do is change the size of the map, but not the position. Somehow the `<iframe>` is still rendered above the set of `<fields>` but I need it to be rendered inside the `<table>` in the second row (sort_order 20). I just don't understand why the `<iframe>` is rendered first (without the `<label>` and `<comment>` which I defined in `system.xml`) and then the `<table>` is rendered afterwards, with only one row...

Answer (score -1):

Well for that you can code in phtml file in design folder you dont need to take iframe as a field take textfield
here's what i have done for video slider

1.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {

                    $i = $i+1;
                     $item->getTitle($i);
                     $item->getUrl($i);
                     $temp = $item->getUrl();
                     $ytarray=explode("/", $temp);
                            $ytendstring=end($ytarray);
                            $ytendarray=explode("?v=", $ytendstring);
                            $ytendstring=end($ytendarray);
                            $ytendarray=explode("&", $ytendstring);
                            $ytcode=$ytendarray[0]; 
                    ?>";?>
```

2. this is my block code

```
 $fieldset->addField('url', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('videoslider')->__('Enter Video URL'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'style'     => 'width:700px;',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'url',
      ));
```

do this and you are all set!
make this changes in view folder in your module and also make changes in saveaction in controller so you can display it in admin side too.